# How to check if a regular expression failed to find a search string in docx file

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, visual-studio

I'm using

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
                Regex regexText = new Regex(search, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);                      
                docText = regexText.Replace(docText, replace);
}
```

How can I check if that Regex `regexText` found the search string `search` or not?

Comment: `var newDocText = regexText.Replace(docText, replace); if (newDocText != docText) { ... }`

Comment: What does this do? Isn't this just duplicating the `docText = regexText.Replace(docText, replace);` with a new var and comparing the two? I don't quite understand this.

Comment: The `Replace` may change the text. So the test compare the input text against the, possibly, changed text.

Comment: Oh ok. I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to run another regex.Replace but this time using the first returned string as follows:

```
Regex regexText = new Regex(search, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
docText = regexText.Replace(docText, replace);

var newDocText = regexText.Replace(docText, replace);
if (newDocText != docText){ 
    ////They don't match it succeeded. Do something....
}
```